# How to create an image when saving it was the size of A4

Tags: android, pdf, canvas, bitmap

Android. How to create an image when saving it was the size of A4 format. The image will be of the rectangles. I am creating an image on a rectangle with Canvas. Maybe simpler to create a pdf file?

Comment: Sorry but what? Your question is barely understandable.

Comment: How to create the image that it was in a format 210х297 at the exit used Canvas? Sorry for bad English

Comment: Google for screenshot tutorials.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not *really* sure of you question, but here's how to:

**See here to use android to scale an incoming A4 bitmap into a different size**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap

and then look at: drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)

**Take an A4 sized image (297x210mm) and scale it into canvas**.

You use the canvas.context.drawImage() method to take in the full-sized A4 image and scale it down to fit in your canvas.  The code below shows how to automatically resize the canvas to A4 proportions based on the source image.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/FAbBm/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var ScaleDown=.25;
    var A4=new Image();
    A4.onload=function(){
        canvas.width=A4.width*ScaleDown;
        canvas.height=A4.height*ScaleDown;
        ctx.drawImage(A4,0,0,A4.width,A4.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
    A4.src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-GKxNKmWgq8s/UJ8zxWLGz5I/AAAAAAAAAgs/fW-MFuw9BFM/s1600/rieger-tuning-audi-a4.jpg";

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it *might* be "my bad" because I saw "canvas"...but admit it, the OP's question is very hard to understand ;)   --  I'll edit my answer to also point at the android method for scaling bitmaps: drawBitmap(bitmap, sourceRectangle, destinationRectangle, paintDefinitions).